# Neo4j : Running WebUI on a predefined database

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

**OS :** Kubuntu 15.10
**Neo4J Version :** 2.3.1
**Java Version :** JDK 1.8

There are two ways of running a neo4j instance.
 1. Server
 2. Local

In server we need to run `/bin/neo4j start` and the path specified in the server config file needs to be empty, else it will throw error

In local mode i.e shell mode, `/bin/neo4j-shell` again we can run localy or we can specify the `ip:port`, unfotunately we cannot specify `ip:port` with `db:path`.

I am following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_native_java_api_example.htm, in the end, for windows there is a GUI where in we can select the database and we can view in Web Gui `localhost:7474`

**Question:**

**How to start a server locally/remote with WebUI Admin Console on a pre-existing neo4j database?**

**Edit:**

**Neo4J.java**

```
package com.tp.neo4j.java.examples;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Neo4J {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("data/graph.db");
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {

        Node javaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.JAVA);
        javaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "JAVA001");
        javaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Java");
        javaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "25");
        javaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");                

        Node scalaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.SCALA);
        scalaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "SCALA001");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Scala");
        scalaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "20");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

        Relationship relationship = javaNode.createRelationshipTo
        (scalaNode,TutorialRelationships.JVM_LANGIAGES);
        relationship.setProperty("Id","1234");
        relationship.setProperty("OOPS","YES");
        relationship.setProperty("FP","YES");

        tx.success();
    }
       System.out.println("Done successfully");
  }
}
```

**Server properties:** 
`org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db`

**Neo4j properties:**

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
remote_shell_port=1337
```

**Embedded Server properties in Java:**

```
GraphDatabaseService db =dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/opt/neo4j/data/graph.db"));
```

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Run the Java Application. It creates db in the specified path.
2. Modify the server properties in conf folder to point to the path specified in java
3. Start neo4j : `sudo neo4j start` 
   [Neo4J starts successfully if the db path mentioned in the server properties is empty]

**Error**

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server.../opt/neo4j/data/log was missing, recreating...
WARNING: not changing user
process [3484]... waiting for server to be ready.... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

**Log:**

```
2015-12-29 07:35:55.276+0530 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2015-12-29 07:35:55.277+0530 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4ae673d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4ae673d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4ae673d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4ae673d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /opt/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@2895e461' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: '/opt/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version '\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00'.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:636)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 15 more
```

**Note:** We can import only csv files, we cannot import a pre-existing neo4j db.

**Note:** Tried [Java Rest Binding](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding), but it seems to have lot issues, Maven issue, dependency issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

**Make sure the jdbc driver version matches your neo4j server version.**

Neo4J Server download: [Neo4j v2.3.1](http://neo4j.com/business-subscription/?edition=enterprise&release=2.3.1&flavour=unix)

**POM Dependency**

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking. You can run Neo4j with the Admin interface on database files on disk by setting the database path in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` pointing to your database store location.